# JS Turning Radio Button into algorithm param

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple program that generates a random build for an NBA 2k21 MyPlayer for one of my classes. Every button the user clicks generates a random value for each trait.

I am now trying to alter the program to remember the user input for the height radio buttons and then generate a random position based on that user's selection.
I want the program to randomize between:

PG/SG if the height is between 6'2" and 6'5" or
SG/SF if the height is between 6'5" and 6'8" or
SF/PF if the height is between 6'8" and 6'10" or
PF/C if the height is between 6'10 and 6'11"

Originally the program was just 3 buttons that generates random values from an array, but now it consists of 3 buttons and a user selection of radio buttons. Here is what I had before I got stuck:

```
<h1>
 2k Archetype Generator
</h1>
<p>
  Choose Height
</p>
<form>

<input name="height" type="radio" id="h1"> 6'2"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h2"> 6'3"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h3"> 6'4"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h4"> 6'5"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h5"> 6'6"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h6"> 6'7"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h7"> 6'8"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h8"> 6'9"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h9"> 6'10"
<br>
<input name="height" type="radio" id="h10"> 6'11"
<br>

</form>
<br>
<button id="positionchoice" onclick="randpos()">
 Position
</button>
<p id="pos">

</p>      
<button id="primary" onclick="randprim()">
  Primary
</button>
<p id="no1">

</p>
        
<button id="secondary" onclick="randsecond()">
  Secondary
</button>
<p id="no2">

</p>
```

```
var p = document.getElementById("pos");
var skill1 = document.getElementById("no1");
var skill2 = document.getElementById("no2");
var height = ["6'2","6'3","6'4","6'5","6'6","6'7"
              ,"6'8","6'9","6'10","6'11"];
 var primary = ["Shot Creating", "Playmaking", "Defensive"
                ,"Sharpshooting","3-Point","Rebounding"];
        
var secondary = ["Slasher", "Finisher", "Shooter",
                 "Ball Handler","Lockdown", "Two-Way"];
        
var arr = ["PG", "SG", "SF", "PF", "C"];
                            
function randpos() {

}
        
function randprim() {
 skill1.innerHTML = primary[Math.floor(Math.random()*primary.length)];
}
        
function randsecond() {
 skill2.innerHTML = secondary[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondary.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help get you unstuck so that you can write the next part of your function. Here is how you can get the currently selected option:

```js
function randpos() {
  let height = document.querySelector("input[name='height']:checked").value;
  height = parseInt(height);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  2k Archetype Generator
</h1>
<p>
  Choose Height
</p>
<form>

  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h1" value="74"> 6'2"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h2" value="75"> 6'3"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h3" value="76"> 6'4"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h4" value="77"> 6'5"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h5" value="78"> 6'6"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h6" value="79"> 6'7"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h7" value="80"> 6'8"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h8" value="81"> 6'9"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h9" value="82"> 6'10"
  <br>
  <input name="height" type="radio" id="h10" value="83"> 6'11"
  <br>

</form>
<br>
<button id="positionchoice" onclick="randpos()">
 Position
</button>
```

I have edited your `<input/>` elements to include a `value` attribute so that you can then select that directly from the JS. Additionally you may notice that these values are in inches only. You can make these values in feet and inches, like are still displayed to the user, but it is likely going to make your life easier implementing the next part of your function if you have a single number you can make comparisons with.

In the JavaScript since your button is not attached to a form you want to set up a query selector looking for any `<input/>` element with a `name` set to `height`. To get only the currently selected element we then look for the [`:checked` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked). Finally we get the value of the element that is returned and assign it to a `height` variable. (Alternatively you can [attach your button to the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form) if you give the form a name which then would allow you to process it in a more typical fashion)

Since you are likely going to want to make comparisons with this value you can then take the `height` variable, a string, and convert it to a number using the `parseInt()` function.